X-ray mode stopped working in Material Preview in a specific file
I have a specific .blend file I'm working with where X-ray mode seems to no longer be working in Material Preview, in Edit Mode. When I turn it on, all it does is make the edges of the mesh kinda thick, but it doesn't show the faces and edges and vertices behind the current frontface. X-ray works fine in Solid mode, and in other files' Material Preview mode, but not this specific file.
Here's an example of a file where X-ray does work in Material Preview, versus the file that I'm having trouble with.


How did I break it? How do I fix it?
